# Laravel 10.41.0 で Livewire 3.x のコンポーネントが動作しません

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

下記現象につき、対策の助言をいただきたく、よろしくお願い致します。
類似の現象を検索しましたが、該当する例を発見できず、対策の試行にも至っておりません。

### 現象

ページに埋め込んだlivewireのviewは表示されます。
埋め込んだviewには、クリック操作でコンポーネントの呼び出しボタンを記述してあります。
そのボタンをクリックしても呼び出し先の処理が動作しません （本件の現象）

### 環境

- さくらインターネットのVPS
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2023 11:41:11) (NTS)
  ※ PHP 8.2.14 (cli) (built: Dec 21 2023 20:19:50) (NTS) でも本件は同様。
- Laravel Framework 10.41.0
- Livewire 3
- Apache2、DB(MySQL) などの基本設定は完了しWEBサーバとして機能。
- Larabel + Breeze でのWEBアプリは動作することが確認できた状態。
- 下記の２つのケースとも、ディレクトリとファイルのオーナー及びグループはapache2実行ユーザ
- 下記の２つのケースとも、ディレクトリとファイルの権限は全て 755 に設定。

### 現象を確認したケース

以下の２つのケースで現象を確認しています。

#### ケース１

1. 新規生成したLaravelプロジェクトのWelcome画面の表示 （成功）
2. このプロジェクトに Jetstream を Livewire 付きでインストール
3. Livewireのpublishを実行
4. Welcome画面からユーザ登録画面に遷移し、ユーザ登録（成功）
5. ログイン後のダッシュボードで、ナビゲーションバー右端のユーザ名にマウスカーソルを持っていくと該当部分の表示が変わる。
6. サンプルとして公開されているカウンター(ボタンクリックでカウントアップ)を実装
7. Welcome画面には、埋め込んだLivewireのviewが表示される
8. その部分をクリックしてもドロップダウンメニューが表示されない（本件の現象）

#### ケース２

1. 新規生成したLaravelプロジェクトのWelcome画面の表示 （成功）
2. このプロジェクトに Jetstream を Livewire 付きでインストール
3. Livewireのpublishを実行
4. このプロジェクトのWelcome画面を、Livewiteのviewを埋め込むコードに変更
5. artisanコマンドでLivewireのコンポーネントを生成
6. サンプルとして公開されているカウンター(ボタンクリックでカウントアップ)を実装。
7. Welcome画面には、埋め込んだLivewireのviewが表示される
8. この画面のボタンにマウスカーソルを持っていくと該当部分の表示が変わる
9. このボタンをクリックしてもカウントアップされない（本件の現象）

### ケース２のソース

resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <livewire:counter>
        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

resources/views/livewire/counter.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h2>{{ $count }}</h2>
    <p><button wire:click="inc">+1</button></p>
</div>
```

app/Livewire/Counter.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 10;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }

        public function inc(){
                $this->count++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

関連サイトを参考にして解決しましたので、報告まで。

## 原因

routes/web.php への下記 Livewire関連ルートの設定不足。

① /livewire/livewire.js
② /livewire/update

## 解決経緯

WEBクライアントのデベロッパーツールのコンソールにて上記２件の Not Found エラーを検出。

### ナビゲーションメニューのドロップダウンメニューが表示されない問題

原因①の Not Found が発生していた。下記のページを発見し、当方の環境に合わせて対応することで解決。

[v3 livewire.js Not Found on production server · livewire/livewire · Discussion #6573](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/6573)

具体的には下記。

```
cp -r -f vendor/livewire/livewire/dist public/livewire
```

routes/web.php への追記。

```
use Livewire\Livewire;
Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
    ★ いくつかの指定の記述あり（関連サイト①参照）
    return Route::get($rootFolder . '/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
});
```

しかし、view上のカウンター機能は動作せず。

### view上のカウンターが動作しない問題

原因②の Not Found が発生していた。下記のページを発見し、当方の環境に合わせて対応することで解決。

[404 return for every update request in livewire. · livewire/livewire · Discussion #6960](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/6960)

ただし、このページの記述方法のままでは動作せず、前述の [Discussion #6573](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/6573) での記述方法を参考に記述を修正。

具体的には下記。routes/web.php へ追記。

```
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    ★ いくつかの指定の記述あり（関連サイト②参照）
    return Route::get($rootFolder . '/livewire/update', $handle);
});
```

## 所見

Livewire3 のオフィシャルサイト掲載の手順でプロジェクトにインストールしたが、それだけでは動作せず、その点についての不満はあるが、このような仕組みを無償公開していただけていることについては感謝しかない。
また、前掲の関連サイトで解答を寄せて下さっている方についても、やはり多大の感謝。

あと、「WEBクライアントのデベロッパーツール」、超大事！

以上です。